# How to filter array of array objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to filter array of array objects. when variable matches with array of object value of dropDownOne key 'filterValue', then it will return dropDownTwo array,

```
 let testName = ‘ filterValue’

 var nestedArray =  [
      [
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "filterValue",
                  value: "test1"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey1",
                      value: "test123"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey2",
                      value: "test345"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],

[
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "NoFilter",
                  value: "test2"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "dropDown2",
                      value: "test"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "dropDown3",
                      value: "test"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
    ]




  Output = 
    
     dropDownTwo:[
                      {
                          key: "retrieveArrKey1",
                          value: "test123"
                      },
                      {
                          key: "retrieveArrKey2",
                          value: "test345"
                      }
                  ]
```

Tried with this

```
 let filterObj = nestedArray.filter((arr => arr.filter(value => {
        if (value[0].dropDownOne.key === 'filterValue') {
          return arr[1];
        }
      }))
```

But did not get the correct result

Comment: `filter` needs to return boolean value

Comment: do you really have the outer objects wrapped insiide of an array with only one object?

Comment: just ask ChatGPT, no need to actually wait for a random human response any more :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Array.flat()` and `Array.flatMap()` combined with `Array.filter()` to do it

```
let result = nestedArray.flat().filter(e => e.dropDownOne.key === testName).flatMap(e => e.dropDownTwo)
console.log(result)
```

```js
let testName = `filterValue`

 var nestedArray =  [
      [
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "filterValue",
                  value: "test1"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey1",
                      value: "test123"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey2",
                      value: "test345"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],

[
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "NoFilter",
                  value: "test2"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "dropDown2",
                      value: "test"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "dropDown3",
                      value: "test"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
    ]
    
let result = nestedArray.flat().filter(e => e.dropDownOne.key === testName).flatMap(e => e.dropDownTwo)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way :

```
nestedArray.filter(arr => arr.find(item=> item.dropDownOne.key === 'filterValue'))[0][0].dropDownTwo
```

```js
var nestedArray =  [
      [
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "filterValue",
                  value: "test1"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey1",
                      value: "test123"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "retrieveArrKey2",
                      value: "test345"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],

[
          {
              dropDownOne: {
                  key: "NoFilter",
                  value: "test2"
              },
              dropDownTwo: [
                  {
                      key: "dropDown2",
                      value: "test"
                  },
                  {
                      key: "dropDown3",
                      value: "test"
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
    ]




const result = nestedArray.filter(arr => arr.find(item=> item.dropDownOne.key === 'filterValue'))[0][0].dropDownTwo


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use both `flat()` to flatten the `nestedArray`, then use the `find()` method to find the object with a `dropDownOne.key` that matches the value of testName.

it should then return the `dropDownTwo` property of that object.

```
let result = nestedArray.flat().find(obj => obj.dropDownOne.key === testName);
let filterObj = result ? result.dropDownTwo : [];
    
console.log(filterObj);
```

a full running example:

```js
let testName = 'filterValue';

var nestedArray = [
  [{
    dropDownOne: {
      key: "filterValue",
      value: "test1"
    },
    dropDownTwo: [{
        key: "retrieveArrKey1",
        value: "test123"
      },
      {
        key: "retrieveArrKey2",
        value: "test345"
      }
    ]
  }],

  [{
    dropDownOne: {
      key: "NoFilter",
      value: "test2"
    },
    dropDownTwo: [{
        key: "dropDown2",
        value: "test"
      },
      {
        key: "dropDown3",
        value: "test"
      }
    ]
  }]
]

let result = nestedArray.flat().find(obj => obj.dropDownOne.key === testName);
let filterObj = result ? result.dropDownTwo : [];
    
console.log(filterObj);
```

Comment: Will throw an error in case, `find` returned `undefined`

Comment: oops moment solved! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't like other solutions due to too many array iterations. You could make a single run using `reduce` function which is a grandfather of many JS Array functions. It looks a bit worse than `flat-filter-flat-...`, but will probably work way faster due to much lower array iterations.

```js
const testName = 'filterValue';
const nestedArray = [
  [{
    dropDownOne: {key: 'filterValue', value: 'test1'},
    dropDownTwo: [
      {key: 'retrieveArrKey1', value: 'test123'},
      {key: 'retrieveArrKey2', value: 'test345'},
    ],
  }],
  [{
    dropDownOne: {key: 'NoFilter', value: 'test2'},
    dropDownTwo: [
      {key: 'dropDown2', value: 'test'},
      {key: 'dropDown3', value: 'test'},
    ],
  }],
];

const result = nestedArray.reduce((acc, nestedItem) => {
  nestedItem.forEach(item => {
    if (item.dropDownOne.key === testName) {
      acc.push(item.dropDownTwo);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```